# How to get a Id from code behind (aspx.vb) to a Dim variable on .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I have a code behind aspx.vb that have a variable.

And I want to use it on the .aspx web page.

eg.

```
Public Class proventos_rendimento_distribuicoes_amortizacoes
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim id_to_use As String = ""

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            lblCustomerId.Text = Me.Page.RouteData.Values("nome_artigo").ToString()
            id_to_use = Me.Page.RouteData.Values("nome_artigo").ToString()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I want to use it on .aspx with something like <%= id_to_use %>

e.g.

```
<b>Customer Id:</b>
<asp:Label ID="lblCustomerId" runat="server" />
<br />
<b><%= id_to_use %></b>
```

But this doesn't work.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Call `Page.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`. The variable also needs to be `Protected` or `Public` because the codebehind class is the parent class of the aspx class, so they are two different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to declare Dim id_to_use As String = "" to public:

```
public Dim id_to_use As String = ""

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        lblCustomerId.Text = Me.Page.RouteData.Values("nome_artigo").ToString()
        id_to_use = Me.Page.RouteData.Values("nome_artigo").ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Protected` should work as well, if you don't want the member to be `Public`.  It's like any other class relationship, the page UI simply inherits from the code-behind class.